# Maven Perforce plugin suddenly requires a password?

Tags: version-control, plugins, maven, perforce, maven-plugin

In my pom.xml I have:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:perforce://path_to_my_repository</connection>
</scm>
```

This has worked fine until recently.  Now when I build I receive the following message:

```
"password is required for the perforce scm plugin."
```

The maven documentation for the plugin does not specify a way to include a password (http://maven.apache.org/scm/perforce.html).

What is going on?  How to I get past this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the error message did not match the problem.  The 'password' needed message appears to be a catch-all message when something goes wrong.  We found the error was a result of a invalid dependency that was introduced.  This was fixed and the prompt for the password disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You could be using a version of the plugin which has this bug ([SCM-415](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-415)).  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300395/how-to-force-maven-scm-perforce-provider-version) SO question has a related problem.

Comment: Its the same version we have been using for weeks.  I am not sure why it is complaining now.  We did refactor the pom's recently, so I am wondering if we need to add or remove some information to get this to work again. I tried adding login info for the maven scm plugin, but that did not resolve the problem.